# finding branch cuts from a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

Consider the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 +1}$, that is, the principal value of the function $(z^2 +1)^{1/2}$. Determine the branch cuts of $f(z)$; check the discontinuity of the branch along the branch cuts.

This is the problem i was given. My problem is that i have no idea what branch cuts are. This year the course got a new professor who just copied a lot of stuff from the last but his lectures are very behind so he hasn't explained what those are and i cant find it in the book.

(and i am an astronomy student following an mandatory math course(complex analysis) so it might have been explained in earlier courses for math students i dont know).

Can someone please explain what i have to do with the branches?

Comment: This probably answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949614/branch-cuts-for-sqrtz21

Comment: Also this may help you understand branch cuts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245579/how-does-a-branch-cut-define-a-branch/247818#247818